# How to save a .py file avoiding save_as command

Tags: save, pysimplegui, save-as

is there any chance to save a .py file without the "save as" pop up si showed up?
In the simple GUI I've created, the first file saving is by the button **Save As** with the filename taken form the text in the first input field. Once the file is saved further modification should be catch by the button **Save**, with the same filename, and without any pop up window is displayed.

```
'''import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sg.theme('DarkTeal9')      

layout_1 = [[sg.InputText("", key='-FILE-', font='Arial 9', size=(10,1)),
             sg.InputText("", key='-INPUT-', font='Arial 9', size=(10,1))]]
layout_2 = [[sg.Button ("Save As")]]
layout_3 = [[sg.Button('Save')]]

layout = [
          [sg.Column(layout_1, key='-LAY1-')],
          [sg.Column(layout_2, key='-SAVE_AS-'), sg.Column(layout_3, key='-SAVE-', visible=False),
           sg.Button ("Load"), sg.Button('Exit'),],
          ]
window = sg.Window("", layout, finalize = True)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
        window.close()

    elif event == 'Save As':
        d = window['-FILE-'].get()
        filename = sg.popup_get_file('', save_as=True, no_window=True, file_types=(("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")), initial_folder=script_path, default_path = d)
        window.SaveToDisk(filename)
        window['-SAVE_AS-'].update(visible=False)
        window['-SAVE-'].update(visible=True)
    if event == 'Save':
        d = window['-FILE-'].get()
        filename = sg.popup_get_file('', save_as=True, no_window=True, file_types=(("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")), initial_folder=script_path, default_path = d)
        window.SaveToDisk(filename)
        window['-SAVE_AS-'].update(visible=False)
        window['-SAVE-'].update(visible=True)                                                       
    if event == 'Load':
        file_name = sg.popup_get_file('Load', no_window=True)
        window.LoadFromDisk(file_name)

window.close()'''
```

Comment: Hello, would please someone help me with this topic? It would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't seem that you really tried to solve the problem yourself. In the "save" section, the second line is about opening a popup - which is, what you don't want. What about starting by removing that line and then trying to figure out, where to store the filename?

Comment: What I've written is only the last attempt trying to figure out the issue. I worked on it for several days, but I recognize my knowledge about python and programming in general is not so advanced.

Comment: btw: thanks for your comment Florian

Comment: Hi there, "problem solved" quite trivially: '''if event == 'Save':
                                                                     window.SaveToDisk(filename)'''